# How to load a webpage using Nightmare JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am using Nightmare JS to create a web bot that visits Facebook's Marketplace and renews the first listing for me. However, only the navigation bar loads when the bot runs and the rest of the body is left blank. I am curious how I can load this, otherwise I cannot select the marketplace button.

Here is my code so far:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
.viewport(1000, 1000)
  .goto('https://www.facebook.com')
    //type email in the email input #email
  .insert('#email', 'EmailHere')
    //type password in the password input #pass
  .insert('#pass', 'PasswordHere')
  //click the login button #loginbutton
  .click('#loginbutton')

  .wait(10000)

  //click on marketplace button
  .click('div.linkWrap.noCount:nth-of-type(3)')

  //.click('div')
  //.goto('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/selling/')

  .wait(5000)

  .end()
  .then(console.log('Nightmare has ended'))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  });
```